# Поиск элемента по имени

Tags: android, java

Нужно найти элемент по имени. Нашел в [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) это решение. Но проблема в том, что возвращает getResource мне всегда нули в этом случае:

```
int z = getResources().getIdentifier("R.drawable.bag", "String", getPackageName());
```

Если же я задаю картинку стандартно:

```
ImageView ivLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogoV);
ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.bag);
```

то все отображается верно. 
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо немного по другому:

```
int z = getResources().getIdentifier("bag", "Drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не могу + сделать репутации не хватает :(